# How to print text with a placeholder replaced by a value from a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash

I am not sure I even state this properly.

Here is what I have in a bash script

```
ATEXT="this is a number ${i} inside a text string"
```

then I want `${i}` to be resolved during the following `for` loop.

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "${ATEXT}"
done
```

Of course the above does not work because `i` is resolved when the variable `ATEXT` is read.

However, I do not know how to achieve what I want. which is to get the output:

```
this is a number 1 inside a text string
this is a number 2 inside a text string
this is a number 3 inside a text string
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For parameterized text, use `printf`, not `echo`:

```
ATEXT="this is a number %d inside a text string"
for i in {1..3}; do
    printf "$ATEXT\n" "$i"
done
```

See also:

- https://ss64.com/bash/printf.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Answer (score 5):

Probably I would prefer @chepner's answer - but as a good alternative you could also do the following:

```
$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_aText()
{
    printf "this is a number %d inside a text string\n" $1
}

for i in {1..3}; do
    _aText $i
done

$ ./script
this is a number 1 inside a text string
this is a number 2 inside a text string
this is a number 3 inside a text string
```

Comment: I was going to add a shell function to my answer, but now I don't need to.

Comment: Thanks - I replaced `echo` with `printf`. Feels better. :)